# Code formatting - break build when rule is broken

Tags: java, coding-style, static-analysis

I am looking for a code formatter which will break the build if the existing code doesn't match the rules.

`Checkstyle` has some specific rules and has Gradle/Maven tasks, but I am looking exactly for something which will enforce specific code style.

Comment: What code style are you referring to? Google Java Formatter enforced Google's Coding Style. Else, you might have to try something like clang-format.

Comment: Not particular code style. I want something where I can set my own rules of formatting, same like in IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Clang-format allows you to do that. Checkstyle enforces rules as per Google and Sun guidelines. Configurations are provided for the same. As for breaking the build, that's possible too. You can specify your own particular configuration for rules specified within Checkstyle. You're limited to those, though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean Java Regex Matcher?

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: I need something which is easy configurable (like IntelliJ code style) but with ability to break the build so possible with gradle/maven plugin. I don't want to build my own solution from scratch, I am looking for existing library/plugin